# Can not install strongloop

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, loopbackjs, strongloop

Hi we have tried to install strongloop on several different servers all running ubuntu 14.4 and we get the same problem everytime. It fails on the same step. We have completely uninstalled node and npm and followed the guide regarding installing on ubuntu digital ocean. We even created a new droplet with node pre-installed. No luck. Created a droplet with centos and followed instruction. Got to install but when running slc loopback we get a missing module error.

Terminal response
    `npm install -g strongloop

```
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/0.10.40"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'

> heapdump@0.3.7 install /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/0.10.40"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump/build'
 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/src/heapdump.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/addon.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/addon.node: Finished
COPY Release/addon.node
  make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump/build'

 > strong-agent@1.6.4 install /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent
  > node-gyp rebuild || exit 0

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/0.10.40"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/strong-agent/src/strong-agent.o
Killed
root@fabacustest1:~#   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/strong-agent.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/strong-agent.node: Finished
COPY Release/strong-agent.node
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/build'`
```

-- it stops above everytime. We can enter which brings us back to prompt.

Any help would be appreciated 
Thank you
Ray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess that this Droplet has 512mb or so of RAM and does *not* have any swap space configured.

Unfortunately, this isn't enough memory to run `npm install -g strongloop`. The easiest solution is to simply add some swap space so that the kernel isn't forced to kill something when it runs out of memory.

You can add a swapfile as root like so:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024 
# mkswap /swap 
# swapon /swap
```

For more information, see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps

Comment: Great tip for those using a Vagrant Box, as well. I had the same problem and solved it by increasing the RAM allocated to my VirtualBox VM.